# Determining whether array contains any item from another array exactly

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to look for a way to determine whether an array contains any item from another array exactly

So far I have:

```
arrayA = ['Shirts']
arrayB = ['Shirts', 'Pants', 'Shorts']

if( arrayA.some(v=> arrayC.indexOf(v) !== -1) ) {
  match = true                      
}
```

Which is correct.

but when the arrays includes 'T-Shirts' rather than simply 'Shirts':

```
arrayA = ['Shirts']
arrayB = ['T-Shirts', 'Pants', 'Shorts']
```

It is also true because 'T-Shirts' contains 'Shirts'

Is there a way to make sure arrayB contains arrayA exactly.

Note that sometimes arrayA can include multiple objects eg.

```
arrayA = ['Shirts', 'Pants']
```

and it should match true if arrayB includes either 'Shirts' or 'Pants'

Comment: `match` won't return true because `['T-Shirts', 'Pants', 'Shorts'].indexOf('Shirts') === -1`. And your present code will work fine if `arrayA` has more than one value in it. So I'm not sure what the question is?

Comment: Ah yes you're right. Turns out my arrayA is never actually an array, it's alway string and what I was after was simply: arrayB.indexOf(arrayA) > -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. But it turns out my arrayA is never actually an array, it's alway string and what I was after was: arrayB.indexOf(arrayA) > -1